# Maven: Surefire --dry-run?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Is there some way to dry-run surefire?
Something which would list which tests **would** run, without running them.

The goal is, to know which tests (would) run in JBoss AS7 testsuite under certain config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a change by Janinko at https://github.com/janinko/maven-surefire/tree/feature/dryrun
Which adds this option:

```
-Dtest.dryrun=true
```

Hopefully it will get to upstream.

UPDATE 2021: Note that this fork of `maven-surefire` has not been updated for 9 years.

Answer (score 2):

No. If you want to verify you are running a subset of your tests under a particular configuration, you will have to do it after the fact via a surefire report or similar.