# Find JUnit 5 Tests in Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, junit5

In our Build Pipeline we would like to know a priori all the test classes (and even better all tests) that would be executed if the build was started.

Is there a maven call or some JUnit5 infrastructure to be used to detect all test(-classes)?

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012686/maven-surefire-dry-run

Comment: Exactly what I'm aiming for. Sadly the mentioned improvement didn't make it into master, at least until 2.21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Launcher` API allows one to *discover* tests without running them. This feature is in fact intended to be used by build tools and IDEs for such "dry runs"; however, I don't think any build tools or IDEs actually use this feature yet.

In any case, you could do it yourself. For details, see the [Discovering Tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-discovery) section of the JUnit 5 User Guide.

Keep in mind that you would need to configure the `Launcher` to discover tests using the same selectors and filters used by Maven Surefire. Otherwise, you might end up with different test plans.