# How to list what tests `mvn test` would run (without actually running)?

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

How to list what tests `mvn test` would run (without actually running)?

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:

```
- `"**/Test*.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
- `"**/*Test.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
- `"**/*Tests.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Tests".
- `"**/*TestCase.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".
```

But when there are many long running tests or mixture of JUnit4 and JUnit5 tests,
it may take a long while to check every test
(Especially for situation when unit test where skipped before)

Is it possible just have idle run? Just see what tests are to be run,
but not actually run them.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running JUnitAndMockitoWorksTest
Running JUnit4AndMockitoWorksTest
Running JUnit5AndMockitoWorksTest
```

UPDATE

There is old [Maven: Surefire --dry-run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012686/maven-surefire-dry-run) that points to https://github.com/janinko/maven-surefire/tree/feature/dryrun
But that fork has not been updated for 9 years, so of course it will not support JUnit 5, etc new things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven: Surefire --dry-run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012686/maven-surefire-dry-run)

Comment: I recommend trying https://www.launchableinc.com/, that runs the unit tests first and then it learns which ones do not need to run using AI (Machine Learning) and the diffs from the commit when the tests ran and your current commit. Another way of doing it is to allow it to run once and them extract these tests from surefire report, version the list of them, and run subsequent runs with `-DskipTests=true`. I am not aware of a flag, but the surefire maven plugin must have a scanning capability ... this can be researched .

Comment: Why are the _unit_ tests slow?  Maybe they're actually integration tests?

Comment: [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe): Yeah! `--dry-run` is scanning the tests! Nice

Comment: @jonrsharpe That should be the answer to close this question
However note, that https://github.com/janinko/maven-surefire/tree/feature/dryrun is fork of surefire not updated for 9 years.